# Sylius Taxonomy Slug Issue

Tags: php, symfony, taxonomy, sylius

Hy.

I recognized that the knp_menu_render displays taxonomy menu wrong.

The problem is that when I create a taxonomy "Wine" and it's subtaxon "White", the slug of the sub-taxon should be **/wine/white** but it isn't.

It will be just **/white**. Moreover the knp_menu_render displays **something.loc//white** so the taxonomy slug is missing for the **wine** taxon.

What can I do to have the correct slug for the taxon?

P.s I'm using a fresh download of sylius-standard.

EDIT (sorry for my english :) )

The demo taxonomy (which works as expected):

[image]

My taxonomy (which has the slug problem):

[image]

And the problem with knp_menu_render twig extension:

[image]

Comment: Could you please edit more details in your question? It's hard to understand what your problem is.

Comment: You have a permalink for the White Taxon, but do you have one for the Wine Taxonomy? What do you see when you go to edit the Wine Taxonomy?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into similar problem ("/" being prepended automatically to the taxon slug, resulting in links being generated with double slashes "//"). The solution I took wasn't very elegant and is only temporary. After creating all the taxons you can execute this query in your database to strip the leading slashes:

`UPDATE sylius_taxon_translation SET permalink = SUBSTR(permalink, 2);`

This obviously isn't ideal since all newly created taxons will have this problem. It all stems from the fact that Taxonomies don't have permalinks.